# How to assign 'UserData' to 'UserData?'

Tags: flutter, dart, undefined

I'm getting weird error,

```
A value of type 'List<UserData>' can`t be assigned 
to the variable of type 'List<UserData>?'
```

[image: Showing exact error]

I think assigning 'UserData?' to 'UserData' is unsafe but, its obvious that I have definitely defined value. How can I add undefinition to make my user data to be accepted by the dart?

Comment: You need to provide code

Answer (score 0):

Just pass **null assertion operator** `!` with object:

```
void myFunction(UserData userData) {
  // use object here
}


myFunction(userData!); // Using ! to assert it's non-null
```

*Make sure to check the object is not `null` while adding **null assertion operator**:*

```
if(userData != null) {
  myFunction(userData!);
} else {
  // data is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the UserData is null or not then assign it using **`!`** to assure that variable is not null.

```
if (userData == null) {
  handleUserDataNull();
} else {
  newUserData = userData!;
}
```

`handleUserDataNull()` is how you react to `userData` that have `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ?? operator:

```
UserData data = userData ?? UserData();
```